# Difference between sys.stdout.write and print when printing variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to learn the difference between `sys.stdout.write` and `print` methods(or functions? Should I call them function or method?)

For example, the code below will print 11

```
a = str(1)
sys.stdout.write (a)
```

But this will print 1

```
a = str(1)
print (a)
```

Why is there such difference? Is there any way to make sys.stdout.write() print 1, not 11?

Thanks!

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/tSXnaOj.png
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The return value for `sys.stdout.write()` returns the no. of bytes written. In this case `1` which also gets printed on the interactive interpret prompt for any expressions entered.

Example:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.write("foo")
foo3
```

If you wanted to hide this you could do this:

```
>>> nbytes = sys.stdout.write("foo\n")
foo
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `sys.stdout.write` returns the value it writes.  So it doesn't print `11`, it prints `1` and returns `1`.  However, if you do this in the interactive interpreter, the interpreter prints the return value of the expression, which is again `1`.

If you don't do it in the interactive interpreter (i.e. you put your code in a file and run it), it won't print the second `1`.  In the interactive interpreter, you can suppress it by assigning the result:

```
x = sys.stdout.write(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess your next execution should throw the same result for both write and print .

As it was not printed in the first time and sits in stdout, it prints all the stdout at the same time i.e. 1 form previous execution and 1 from current execution.

Just try out and let me know :)

Answer (score 2):

To explain you the difference you have to understand print function -

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)
```

Print takes inputs `objects` and writes it to `file` arguement which by default is `sys.stdout` and returns Nothing.
It uses `write` function of `file arguement` object and prints `end` arguement as last character That means it uses
`sys.stdout.write` by default to print statement to the screen . `Sys.stdout.write` returns number of bytes as return value. 
`Print` is some wrapper on top of `sys.stdout.write`.